# Openpyxl Error raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, yfinance

I wrote this code to display the series of contracts for Apple Inc. on Excel, but the data is not displayed on Excel

```
import yfinance as yf
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Gamma"
ticker = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
info = ticker.info
industry = print("industry:",info ["industry"])
Symbol = print("symbol:",info ["symbol"])
Last = print("currentprice:",info ["currentPrice"])
Option = ticker.option_chain('2023-06-23')
ks= print(Option.calls)

ws['A1']= info ["symbol"]
ws['A2']= info ["industry"]
ws['A3']= info ["currentPrice"]
ws['A5']= Option.calls
wb.save("gamm.xlsx")
```

The error that I resave related to this line `ws['A5']= Option.calls`. If I wrote the code with out it the program will create Excel file but only display A1 , A2 and A3

This is the error

```
raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))

ValueError: Cannot convert          contractSymbol             lastTradeDate  ...  contractSize  currency
0   AAPL230623C00070000 2023-05-30 14:09:28+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
1   AAPL230623C00100000 2023-06-05 19:53:22+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
2   AAPL230623C00110000 2023-06-16 17:45:43+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
3   AAPL230623C00115000 2023-06-16 17:34:41+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
4   AAPL230623C00120000 2023-06-16 17:38:58+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
5   AAPL230623C00130000 2023-06-14 14:46:51+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
6   AAPL230623C00135000 2023-06-16 16:11:04+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
7   AAPL230623C00140000 2023-06-16 16:27:40+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
8   AAPL230623C00145000 2023-06-16 15:50:56+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
9   AAPL230623C00148000 2023-06-12 16:40:01+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD
10  AAPL230623C00149000 2023-06-12 17:29:03+00:00  ...       REGULAR       USD

[11 rows x 14 columns] to Excel
```

Comment: `Option.calls` is a `Dataframe` how would you write as the value to a single cell? Also the Python `print` function does not return any value so the lines like `industry = print("industry:",info ["industry"])` are pointless. If you want to print the value then use `print("industry:",info ["industry"])`, if you want to assign `info["industry"]` to the variable `industry` then `industry = info["industry"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the data you want to use `to_excel` from `Pandas` to write the `dataframe` to the Excel sheet;

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

ticker = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
info = ticker.info

print(f'Industry: {info["industry"]}')
print(f'Symbol: {info["symbol"]}')
print(f'Currentprice: {info["currentPrice"]}')

Option = ticker.option_chain('2023-06-23')

### Dataframe for Header; Header and Information 
### Formatted for two rows; row1 Header, row2 Info 
symbol_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Symbol': [info["symbol"]],
    'Market': [info["industry"]],
    'Last Price': [info["currentPrice"]]
})

### Option.calls is a dataframe
options_df = Option.calls
### Need to fix the lasttradeDate as it contains TZ information
options_df['lastTradeDate'] = options_df['lastTradeDate'].dt.tz_localize(None)

### Write the two dataframes to Excel
### Symbol Info first from row 1, then Options df from row 3
with pd.ExcelWriter("gamm.xlsx") as writer:
    symbol_df.to_excel(writer,
                       sheet_name="Gamm",
                       startrow=0,
                       index=False)
    options_df.to_excel(writer,
                        sheet_name="Gamm",
                        startrow=3,
                        index=False)
```

Example Output
[image: Example]

**Note** the default engine used is `'xlsxwriter'` if you like you can switch use it's `autofit()` function to fit the columns to the data. Add the following to the ExcelWriter section to the below;

```py
...
### Write the two dataframes to Excel
### Symbol Info first from row 1, then Options df from row 3
with pd.ExcelWriter("gamm.xlsx") as writer:
    symbol_df.to_excel(writer,
                       sheet_name="Gamm",
                       startrow=0,
                       index=False)
    options_df.to_excel(writer,
                        sheet_name="Gamm",
                        startrow=3,
                        index=False)

    ### xlsxwriter workbook and sheet objects
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Gamm']

    ### Use autofit() function on the worksheet 
    worksheet.autofit()
```

[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)

Comment: Thank you your code work perfectly, but the second part after the note didn't work with it gave me this error `worksheet.autofit()`  `AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'autofit'`

Comment: Make sure your xlsxwriter version is up to date.

Comment: I did that but unfortunately still I face the same problem

Comment: The autofit() function was included in Xlsxwriter `release 3.0.6 on Jan 5 2023`, so an Xlsxwriter worksheet object from this version on should have that attribute.

Comment: You can confirm the `worksheet` in the code is an Xlsxwriter worksheet object and double check the Xlsxwriter version used by the code by adding the following lines after `worksheet = writer.sheets['Gamm']` ; `import xlsxwriter`, `print(xlsxwriter.__version__)`, and `print(type(worksheet))`. The version should be preferably [near] the latest release [3.1.2] but at least `3.0.6` and the worksheet object should print type as something like `<class 'xlsxwriter.worksheet.Worksheet'>`